# How to access web server running on port 3000 on an M1 Mac from an iPhone 13 mini

Tags: mac, iphone

As per the question trying to get to a webserver running on my Mac at port 3000 from iPhone 13 mini.

The server is Next.JS based.

Was I have tried to connect:

1. via cable between the iphone and the mac.
2. By being on the same wireless network.
3. By setting my phone to be a hotspot and using the hotspot as my wireless network.
   This [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132105/) would seem to be helpful  but unfortunately not.

The top rated answer involves using “Network Utility” however “Network Utility” is no longer shipped with the newer versions of macOS and thus you would need to jump through hoops to get it, if you are allowed.

The second answer involves turning on internet sharing. I have tried that.

I have changed my local computer  hostname to be myname.local, thus I can go to a browser in my mac m1 and type myname.local:3000 and get the site being served at my localhost port 3000.

I can also get to my local by entering the url 0.0.0.0:3000 or my local ip address in my browser address bar. I get that local ip address via the following command:

```
ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -Fv 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

When I connect my iphone to my mac and try to go to any of the urls that work in my local browser in safari on the iphone I get a timeout or an error message.

Error messages vary - trying to connect on the local wireless network the error message is:

> Safari cannot open the page.
>
> The Error Was "This URL can't be shown"

which I guess means corporate firewall. I would like to get around the corporate firewall rather than trying to talk to them.

When using the hotspot or connected via cable the message is

> Safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding.

I periodically get the message “Internet Protected by 802.1X” when connecting iphone to mac as explained in [this discussion thread on Apple’s website](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4315430).

In that discussion thread it is suggested to turn off sharing if one gets that message, but with sharing turned off I can't share either - as would be expected.

If I can’t share with sharing turned on and can't share with sharing turned off I am thinking it means I can't share, but maybe Apple has another way to do it?

Comment: `localhost` by very definition means 'this machine', 'me'. It is not possible to contact localhost anywhere but 'here'. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: What @Tetsujin says is correct. If you want to access the application running on port 3000 on the Mac from your iPhone 13, you need to allow that application to be accessible on the `.local` Bonjour network and then access it on your iPhone. Both devices need to be on the same network. Like if your Mac was named `CoolMac` then with Bonjour sharing would be on `CoolMac.local` and port 3000 would be accessed as `CoolMac.local:3000`.

Comment: ok well I mean in vernacular usage trying to go to localhost on my mac port 3000 from my iphone would generally mean to anyone, conversant in English, writing some sort of address in the browser in iphone and getting the website being served on the mac, but I shall edit my post to make this more clear.

Comment: Can you connect if you use the Mac IP address? For example 192.168.1.23:3000 (or whatever your Mac IP is.

Comment: Did you verify that your web server is binding to *:3000 (0.0.0.0:3000), or [your Mac's LAN IP address]:3000, and not just the loopback IP address 127.0.0.1:3000? Because if it's only binding to the loopback IP address, it's intentionally set to only accept connections from your Mac.

Comment: What @Spiff says is correct. If your application is bound only to `localhost`/`127.0.0.1` it will not be accessible off of the Mac. To be able to check it on your iPhone you need to have the application bound to `0.0.0.0`. Also, you state this, “…trying to get to a webserver running…” What kind of web server? A Python or Node application server? Or something else.

Comment: *"When I connect my iphone to my mac"* How are you connected? You question suggests that you're using Internet Connection Sharing, which is going to stop this from working. ICS is in effect a passthrough, not touching the Mac itself. You'd do best with both connected to the same Ethernet or Wifi router, then you just use the local IP address of each.

Comment: on my mac my local ip port 3000, and 0.0.0.0:3000 both work. 
>When I connect my iphone to my mac" How are you connected? @Tetsujin I am connected via cable between iphone and mac. I thought my iphone was connected to same wifi but perhaps not. Will try again.

Comment: @Tetsujin and others. I have updated the question to handle all the scenarios in the comments here. Although now I worry the question is overly verbose and hard to understand.

Comment: 1. & 3.  & any use of connection sharing/hotspot will not work. 2. will work if both devices are on the same subnet. 127.x 0.0.0.0 & localhost are all red herrings. You need to connect to the actual IP address, 192.168… etc.

Answer (score 2):

I can connect lo my Mac from my device using username.local e ip, but if I add the port number I can't connect.
I'm running macOS 13.2.1

on Iphone

http://username.local,
http://192.168.1.45

I get "It Works"

http://username.local:3000,
http://192.168.1.45:3000

not found

of course localhost:3000 from the Mac is working